# Tightest cone fitting a set of directions

Tags: 3d, geometry, data-fitting

Given a set of unit directions in 3D **d_1, ..., d_n**,

How to find the tightest cone around them?

E.g. How can I find another unit vector **m**, and a scalar value **alpha** representing an angle, such that:

foreach i, AngleBetween(**m**, **d_i**) < **alpha**

and **alpha** is minimum.

Note added: directions can span more than an half space. In such a case with 'cone' we means the set of halflines starting from the cone apex and within a given angle from the cone axis.

Answer (score 1):

If your set of directions all fall within one halfspace through the origin, then you could compute the convex hull of the vector tips on the unit-radius sphere, which yields a convex polygon on that sphere, and then find the smallest circle circumscribing that polygon.  You could avoid the spherical calculations by projection to a suitable plane.

I realize this is an abstract view and you likely need more concrete advice, but it still might help: Convex hull + minimum circumscribing circle.

If your set of directions span more than a halfspace, then you would need to define what you mean by "cone" in this circumstance.

Comment: Thanks! Reduction to 2D was also my initial choice. Unfortunately I have directions spanning more than a halfspace...

Comment: When directions span more than a halfspace, find on the unit sphere the largest circle that is empty of all direction tips.  That defines an exterior empty cone.  The cone you want is its complement.

Answer (score 0):

This is a linear programming problem.

Find a, p maximizing cos(a) subject to:
px*d1x+py*d1y*pz*d1z >= cos(a)
px*d2x+py*d2y*pz*d2z >= cos(a)
...
px*dnx+py*dny*pz*dnz >= cos(a)

I would look into LP algorithms. Meanwhile, I've solved a very similar problem that could be a jumping off point: https://github.com/VictorDavis/GeoConvexHull. You're correct, once you DO find the convex hull, you can then find the minimum circumscribing circle. As it turns out though, proving n points lie in the same hemisphere is non-trivial. Maybe this algorithm can be tailored to answer your "smallest cone" problem.