# Construct a cone from a set of k points given apex point i in python?

Tags: python, scipy, computational-geometry

Suppose you have k n-dimensional points `{p1, p2, ..., pk}` and we pick a point `i`  (`1 <= i <= k`). How would one compute the tightest fitting cone with tip `pi`? As well as the [pointedness](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-006-0069-1) of said cone?

For a similar question about tightest fitting cones, user [@Joseph O'Rourke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387778/joseph-orourke) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14140689/5623899)

> If your set of directions all fall within one halfspace through the origin, then you could compute the convex hull of the vector tips on the unit-radius sphere, which yields a convex polygon on that sphere, and then find the smallest circle circumscribing that polygon. You could avoid the spherical calculations by projection to a suitable plane.
> I realize this is an abstract view and you likely need more concrete advice, but it still might help: Convex hull + minimum circumscribing circle.

So how would one compute this in python?
There is the [cone programming](https://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html) library and SciPy's [convex hull](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html).

From a naive perspective, I feel like the angle / pointedness of the cone can be computed as follows (at least in 2d, were the angle of a cone and an arc are equivalent?)

```
given: point i
pick another point j, 1<=j<=k, j!=i

min_theta = 0

for each point p, p!=i, p!=j
   cur_theta = arc angle from j to p
   if cur_theta > min_theta: # point is outside our minimal 2d arc
       min_theta = cur_theta
```

Comment: What do you mean by tightest fitting "cone"? The notion of a "cone" disintegrates more and more as you add more dimensions. For example, the quote you have suggests that you know a certain plane should have constant curvature (e.g. xy plane in 3d) and you could create a nonlinear minimization enforcing that constraint while forming a convex hull. But, which plane and how rigorous is the constraint? Do you really want that, or do you just want an ND linear fit centered at point pi?

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren I am not entirely sure... So I am thinking in the 2d / 3d case (but would like the notion to generalize). By "tightest" in the 2d case I mean the smallest angel theta which, given the starting point can contain all other points. In the 3d case, I suppose if you start at point i , it would be the diameter of the smallest circle which contains all other points? I get what Joseph O'Rourke was saying about halfplanes, but from an algorithmic perspective I don't really mind (as these cones would not be "sharp")

Comment: You need to split the question for 2D and 3D cases. A cone is a 3D object. For 2D case, use the term, circular sector. I think mathematical models for two cases are different to each other.

Comment: @relent95 can you answer it for the 3d case?

Comment: Based on what you're saying, I think a solution for you is to project your points onto a line/plane/hyperplane and fit a convex hull (again this can get really wonky when the dimensions go up). From the convex hull you can get a minimum "radius" that defines the base of your cone.